# CSS - Can the order of layout be responsive aswell as the number of columns per row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is it possible to configure the order of content boxes to be flexible in bootstrap, and not just the number of boxes per row? The following is the responsive layout I'm trying to achieve.

In the past I've maintained separate content versions for different screen sizes, but with a rewrite comes the opportunity to change how it all works and introduce newer practices such as this.

[image: Bootstrap Layout Configuration]

Block *B* coloured blue is the company name and logo so needs to be kept at the top and central, while other content in *A*, *C*, *D* and *F* will fall into place around *B*. Block *E* is essentially footer text and small print - copyright notice and some links etc.

If this is not possible with Bootstrap layouts please suggest an alternative that will help me to accomplish this.

The content and layout requirements such as how the content looks is not up to me, I'm just trying to follow some best practice and make the site mobile tablet and desktop browser-friendly so that moving forward it will be simpler to maintain. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the _push_ and _pull_ classes in the [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) section of Bootstrap's documentation. The order in your html should be based on the mobile layout. If that doesn't work and you don't need to support older browsers take a look at flexbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to implement your example to show this can be done using Bootstrap's column ordering classes, e.g. `col-md-push-4` and `col-md-pull-4`.

This only works if the boxes have equal height, try adding `.box--high` to box *A* to see what sort of issues might occur if this isn't the case. These issues can be solved by nesting Bootstrap's grid classes, but you will also need to duplicate some of the boxes and show or hide them at specific layout sizes using e.g. `.hidden-xs`.

Flexbox (`display: flex`) might be an option if you don't need to support older browsers (IE9 and IE10). See [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
.box {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  margin-bottom: 15px;  
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.box.box--blue {
  background-color: #9CCCE8;
}

.box.box--high {
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
      <div class="box box--blue">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
      <div class="box">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="box">C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="box">D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
      <div class="box">F</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
      <div class="box">E</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox css model.

On parent div/element assign:-

```css
parentElement {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
}
```

In media queries based upon your ordering assign the following on child element:-

```css
childElement {
   order: 3; /*any integer*/
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
   childElement {
   order: 1; /*any integer*/
   }
}
```